# Several Google Chrome Helper orphan processes

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome keeps leaving GCH processes behind, even after stopping the main process. How can I quickly kill all GCH processes in one go?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these aren't zombie processes (ones that can't be killed), you can try pasting the following command into Terminal:

```
killall Google\ Chrome\ Helper
```